# Google Maps JS API with multiple HTML select filters and array values

Tags: json, google-maps, select, filter, maps

I'm working on a custom store locator based on the Google Maps JS API and I am retrieving all the location data from a JSON file. Every store can be filtered by a combination of select filters.

My goal is to filter by "type of store" (string), "brands" (array of brands) and "tailor" (string). Filtering by string (single value) works perfectly, but I'm stuck on the "brands" filter. The script can't match a value from within the array. So my question is: what do I need to modify to achieve a combination of string + array filters?

I'm using the following code: https://codepen.io/xtiggerk/pen/GBNPdO

```
var json = [
      {
        "title" : "Store A",
        "type" : "boutique",
        "brands" : ["Brand A", "Brand B", "Brand C"],
        "tailor" : "tailora",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            0.48339843749999994,
            46.89023157359399
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "title" : "Store B",
        "type" : "boutique",
        "brands" : ["Brand D", "Brand E", "Brand F"],
        "tailor" : "tailorb",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            2.7685546874999996,
            47.76148371616669
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "title" : "Store C",
        "type" : "mall",
        "brands" : ["Brand A", "Brand B", "Brand C"],
        "tailor" : "tailora",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            2.57080078125,
            45.882360730184025
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "title" : "Store D",
        "type" : "mall",
        "brands" : ["Brand D", "Brand E", "Brand F"],
        "tailor" : "tailorb",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -0.098876953125,
            44.52001001133986
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "title" : "Store E",
        "type" : "popupstore",
        "brands" : ["Brand A", "Brand B", "Brand C"],
        "tailor" : "tailora",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            4.54833984375,
            45.874712248904764
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "title" : "Store F",
        "type" : "popupstore",
        "brands" : ["Brand D", "Brand E", "Brand F"],
        "tailor" : "tailorb",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            4.822998046875,
            45.920587344733654
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
var jsonStringify = JSON.stringify(json)
var jsonParse = JSON.parse(jsonStringify); 

var markers = [];
var markerCluster;
var searchInput = jQuery('#searchMap input');
var filterSelect = jQuery('.filter');
var resetButton = jQuery('#resetFilter');



var filterResults = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var filters = json[i];
    var filtertype = filters.type;
    var filterbrands = filters.brands;
    var filtertailor = filters.tailor;
    filterResults.push(filtertype, filterbrands, filtertailor);       
}

var filterStringify = JSON.stringify(filterResults)
var filterParse = JSON.parse(filterStringify);   


function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.882360730184025, 2.57080078125)
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        setMarkers(json[i], map);
    }

    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {ignoreHiddenMarkers: true, imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}

function setMarkers(marker, map) {
    var markerMap = marker.geometry.coordinates;
    var title = marker.title;
    var type = marker.type;
    var brands = marker.brands;
    var tailor = marker.tailor;
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markerMap[1], markerMap[0]);
    var content = marker;

    markerMap = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        title: title,
        type: type,
        brands: brands,
        tailor: tailor,
        map: map
    });

    markers.push(markerMap);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: title + '<br/>' + type + '<br/>' + brands + '<br/>' + tailor 
    });    

    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerMap, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, markerMap);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
            // map.setZoom(15);
        }
    })(markerMap, content));
}

function clusterManager(array) {
    markerCluster.clearMarkers();
    if (!array.length) {
        jQuery('.alert').addClass('is-visible');
    } else {
        jQuery('.alert').removeClass('is-visible');
        for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
            markerCluster.addMarker(array[i]);
        }
    }
}

//@todo add inputsearch
function newFilter(filterType1 = 'all', filterType2 = 'all', filterType3 = 'all') {
    var criteria = [
        { Field: "type", Values: [filterType1] },
        { Field: "brands", Values: [filterType2] },
        { Field: "tailor", Values: [filterType3] },
        // { Field: ["type", "tailor", "brands"], Values: [filterTyped] }
      ];

    var filtered = markers.flexFilter(criteria);
    clusterManager(filtered);
}

Array.prototype.flexFilter = function(info) {
    // Set our variables
    var matchesFilter, matches = [], count;

    // Helper function to loop through the filter criteria to find matching values
    // Each filter criteria is treated as "AND". So each item must match all the filter criteria to be considered a match.
    // Multiple filter values in a filter field are treated as "OR" i.e. ["Blue", "Green"] will yield items matching a value of Blue OR Green.
    matchesFilter = function(item) {
      count = 0
      for (var n = 0; n < info.length; n++) {
        if (info[n]["Values"].indexOf(item[info[n]["Field"]]) > -1) {
            count++;
        }
        //if value = all, return all item
        else if (info[n]["Values"] == "all") {
            count++;
        }
      }
      // If TRUE, then the current item in the array meets all the filter criteria
      return count == info.length;
    }

    // Loop through each item in the array
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      // Determine if the current item matches the filter criteria
      if (matchesFilter(this[i])) {
        matches.push(this[i]);
      }
    }

    // Give us a new array containing the objects matching the filter criteria
    return matches;
  }



jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.filter-type').on('change', function(){       
    var filter2 = jQuery('.filter-brands').val();
    var filter3 = jQuery('.filter-tailor').val();
    newFilter(jQuery(this).val(), filter2, filter3);
  });

  jQuery('.filter-brands').on('change', function(){
    var filter1 = jQuery('.filter-type').val();
    var filter3 = jQuery('.filter-tailor').val();
    newFilter(filter1, jQuery(this).val(), filter3);
  });

  jQuery('.filter-tailor').on('change', function(){
    var filter1 = jQuery('.filter-type').val();
    var filter2 = jQuery('.filter-brands').val();
    newFilter(filter1, filter2, jQuery(this).val());
  });

    searchInput.on('keyup', function () {
          var searchTyped = $(this).val();
          var arr = [];
          if (searchTyped.length > 0) {
              jsonParse.filter(function() {
                  for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                      marker = markers[i];
                      var markerFilter = [];
                      var filtertype = marker.type;
                      var filterbrands = marker.brands;
                      var filtertailor = marker.tailor;

                      markerFilter.push(filtertype, filterbrands, filtertailor); 
                      var markerFilterStringify = JSON.stringify(markerFilter);
                      if( markerFilterStringify.indexOf(searchTyped) >= 0) {
                          arr.push(marker);
                      } else {
                          console.log('dont fit requirement')
                      }
                  }
              });
              clusterManager(arr);
          } else {
              newFilter();
          }
      });

    resetButton.on('click', function() {
        searchInput.val('');
        filterSelect.val('all');
        newFilter();
    });

    //delete all duplicated value from the previous array
    var uniqueValue = [];
    jQuery.each(filterResults, function(i, el){
        if(jQuery.inArray(el, uniqueValue) === -1) {
            uniqueValue.push(el);
        } 
    });

    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substringRegex;
        matches = [];

        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

        jQuery.each(strs, function(i, str) {
            if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
            matches.push(str);
            }
        });
        cb(matches);
        };    
    };
    searchInput.typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        tailor: 'customFilter',
        source: substringMatcher(uniqueValue)
    });

});


jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
    initMap();
});
```

Comment: Maybe this?  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change your `matchesFilter` function as follows:

```
matchesFilter = function(item) {
    count = 0
    for (var n = 0; n < info.length; n++) {

        var values = info[n]["Values"];
        var fieldArr = item[info[n]["Field"]];

        if (values.indexOf(fieldArr) > -1) {
            count++;
        }
        //if value = all, return all item
        else if (values == "all") {
            count++;
        } else {
            //if value is an array, loop through it to find a match using includes() method
            if (values instanceof Array) {
                for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
                    if (fieldArr.includes(values[j])) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // If TRUE, then the current item in the array meets all the filter criteria
    return count == info.length;
}
```

Hope this helps!